# adding multiple functions to an ExtJS gridPanel button's handler

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS gridPanel with a button that fires a global function:

```
grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
    tbar: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Group',
            handler: group // call to global function
        }
    ]
...
});
```

After I have called the `group` function, I need to call another global function, for instance `renameGroups`; how do I place this function, or indeed any additional functions, in the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do in JavaScript usually is define our own function calling all the others, so in your example:

```
grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
tbar: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Group',
        // will call the function when clicked, which will then call the others
        handler: function(e) {
            group(e); 
            renameGroups(e);
        }
    }
]
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with relevant code example, that is simple to follow and understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options.

1. Instead of using a handler, you could listen for click from another component. For example:

   grid.down('[text=Group]').on('click', function() {});
2. You can put a function in the grid and call it directly from inside the handler:

   button.up('grid').renameGroups();